# How to set viewrecords property of jqgrid dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I want to set viewrecords property of jqgrid dynamically. By default this property is set as false. I want to set this to true or false (sometimes to show and at times not to show the recordText at the table footer) depending upon the data that I am populating in the grid dynamicaly. I tried with the following but with no avail-

```
jQuery("#gridID").jqGrid({viewrecords : true});    
jQuery("#gridID").setGridParam({viewrecords : true});
```

Comment: You can read [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/147495) how to format the code.

Comment: Sorry for not formatting the code properly as i didnt know how to format.Now as per your suggestion i have formatted my code. i will do the same while posting any question now on.

Comment: It's standard problem of the beginner. So after editing of some of the question I prefer to post the link which describe how to use stackoverflow more effectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use `viewrecords: true` and just hide the `div.ui-paging-info` inside of `loadComplete` depend from the current number of records. For example

```
loadComplete: function (data) {
    if (parseInt(data.records, 10) > 10) {
        $("#pager div.ui-paging-info").show();
    } else {
        $("#pager div.ui-paging-info").hide();
    }
}
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ViewrecordsDynamically.htm) demonstrate the approach. If you open on the demo the searching dialog and filter for the client data equal to `test` you will see only one record and the `viewrecords` field will be not visible:

[image]

Clicking on the "Reload Grid" navigator button will follow to show the `viewrecords` field back.